# ifup: Not enough information: "dev" argument is required

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ifupdown, ifup

On Ubuntu 20.04, I've define following interface in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3   # my meaningful comment
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

When I've trying to bring this interface up I've got an error:

```
# ifup eth0:0
Not enough information: "dev" argument is required.
ifup: failed to bring up eth0:0
```

Answer (score 4):

Root cause of this issue is *inline* comment:
`# my meaningful comment`

The man page for `/etc/network/interfaces` explicitly states this https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html

> Lines starting with `#' are ignored. Note that end-of-line comments
>   are NOT supported, comments must be on a line of their own.